# Conditional Average in Excel For 8 Most Recent Scores >0

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 15 scores or more and I want to average the most recent 8 scores (based on date) that are greater than zero. Here is the example:

```
6/4/15,   
6/18/15, 50  
7/9/15, 46  
7/16/15, 41  
7/23/15, 47  
7/30/15, 47  
8/6/15,   
8/13/15, 46  
8/20/15, 49  
8/27/15, 44  
9/3/15,   
5/5/16, 58  
5/12/16, 53  
5/19/16, 44  
5/26/16, 42
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Is there ever 2 per day or are the days unique?

Comment: Each day will only have one score. See my comment I added below to Tim.

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this array formula:

```
=AVERAGE(IF(($A$1:$A$15>=LARGE(IF($B$1:$B$15<>"",$A$1:$A$15),8))*($B$1:$B$15<>""),$B$1:$B$15))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be entered with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]

---

We can make the formula a little more dynamic by using `INDEX($B:$B,MATCH(1E+99,$A:$A))` to set the last row in the dataset.

Array formulas calculate exponentially, so we want to limit the size of the references to the actual size of the dataset.

What the formula does is it finds the last cell with a number/date in column A and uses that row as the last row.

So putting it all together:

```
=AVERAGE(IF(($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,MATCH(1E+99,$A:$A))>=LARGE(IF($B$1:INDEX($B:$B,MATCH(1E+99,$A:$A))<>"",$A$1:INDEX($A:$A,MATCH(1E+99,$A:$A))),8))*($B$1:INDEX($B:$B,MATCH(1E+99,$A:$A))<>""),$B$1:INDEX($B:$B,MATCH(1E+99,$A:$A))))
```

It is still an array formula so the above condition of using Ctrl-Shift-Enter is still needed.

Answer (score 0):

As a disclaimer, I don't have any screen captures or actual formulae, but you did not show us very much.

First, sort your data in *descending* order by score (<kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>).  This will place all the zero entries at the bottom.  You can now ignore them since you don't want them to be part of your averages.

Next, sort the data having a score greater than zero (i.e. not appearing at the very bottom) by *date* in *descending* order (<kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> again on the date column).

Then just take the average of the first 8 rows after this sort using the `AVERAGE()` function.

Comment: maybe more background is necessary. I am trying to calculate a golf handicap for 30+ people every week. So each week, if a player misses the round, they get a blank. But in order to calculate the handicap it must use the most 8 recent rounds. So sorting each players rounds, to get the zeros near eachother, would not be feasible. I did not include any formulas because I don't have anything yet. The scores are simply inputs each week.